# jQuery && Dajaxice callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm testing usage of dajaxice in a django project, I have completed the examples of the web page, everything is working fine, now I'd like to call the callback inside jQuery's doucment ready. I haven't found any example, everything is pure javaScript, I'm not a JavaScript ninja, but think this is a  javascript scope's issue.

Ex:

```
<script>
    var colores = function colors(data){
        ....
        Magic!
        ....
    }
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         ....
         ....
         Dajaxice.ajax.colors(colores);
         ....
         ....
    });

</script>
```

Note: there is not a dajaxice tag....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems to be ok... anyway you can also create the "colores" function directly before the ready() function. What error you have in the browser?

```
<script>
    function colores (data){
        ....
        Magic!
        ....
    }
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         ....
         ....
         Dajaxice.ajax.colors(colores);
         ....
         ....
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hooops!, mil perdones, sorry, there was another "window.onload" in the code, sorry. Anyway thankyou for dajaxaice and for your cool website ;)